# Modify symbol generated by \thanks using elsart.cls

Tags: symbols, elsarticle

I'm using `elsart.cls` to format a paper I'm writing, but I would really like to use a different symbol for the footnote attached to the title for the acknowledgements.  As it stands now, the `\thanks` command generates a superscript "1" next to the title and uses the acknowledgements as the first footnote.  I'd like to make it a `\dagger` and have the first footnote within the paper be footnote #1.  I have tried this command:

```
\documentclass{elsart}   
\makeatletter   
\renewcommand{\@fnsymbol}[1]{\ifcase#1\or\dagger\else\@arabic{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\fi}   
\makeatother
```

but it does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 4):

`elsarticle` doesn't support the `\thanks` command

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}   

\begin{document}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
\tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is a longer
longer than the first one and with an intention to fill
in up more than one line while formatting.}

\author{foo and bar}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]